# This as parameter in other function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I'm trying to send $(this) as parameter to other function after user clicks on a row and than after click button append some text to clicked row.

My problem is that I want to append only to last clicked row, not to all row's and append text only once

When I click 10 times on row and than click button, text append 10 times.

This is my code:

```
$('#Page').on('click', '.row', function(e) {
  var ths = this;
  addText(ths);
});

function addText(ths) {
  $('.addtext').click(function() {
    $(ths).append('teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest');
    $('#tools').hide();
    ths = null;
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, oh boy, there are multiple problems there... Can you provide full code? HTML as well

Comment: `When I click 10 times on row and than click button, text append 10 times` - In general, not trying to understand why you do it this way, you are adding a new click event each time you click...Use either jQuery `one()` if it suits or remove all bound events from selector and only bind to the desired element. On the other hand why are you binding a click event each time you click on the row?

Comment: Try appending html and not just text in your function `addText(ths)`.  Make sure the HTML has a class or id that you then check with an `if` statement in your original `on('click'...)` call.

Comment: Could you also show us your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Detect clicked row and append it like that:

```
$('.row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).append('Test');
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/35/